# wipe out temporary/useless variables from Locals window

Tags: vba

When I need an "useless" temporary object or variable just for a few lines, I would want it to not dirty the Locals window with its presence at least after its use.

So for example I use to replace this code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim strBaseName$, strExtensionName$
    Dim oFSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    With oFSO
        strBaseName = .GetBaseName(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
        strExtensionName = .GetExtensionName(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    End With
    Stop ' here I unwantedly see oFSO in the Locals window
End Sub
```

with this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim strBaseName$, strExtensionName$
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        strBaseName = .GetBaseName(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
        strExtensionName = .GetExtensionName(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    End With
    Stop  ' here the Locals window is clean
End Sub
```

Is there a way to obtain the same with a variable instead than an object?

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: edited now, the screenshots didn't show up, sorry

Comment: Your code uses objects in both cases... In the second case it is not `Set`. If the set object is problematic for you, please try `Set oFSO = Nothing`, after `End With`.

Comment: @FaneDuru the "Set oFSO = Nothing" doesn't hide it out from the Locals window, this is why I prefer the "With New Scripting.FileSystemObject" (that doesn't even show it in the Locals window).  Now I just need a similar solution for variables

Comment: I am afraid that the main scop of using `Local Window` is to be able to see the used variables values. I (only) thought that clearing it from memory it will not be displayed anymore. It probably show it being `Nothing`... The (big) advantage of using a variable is that after setting it, you may use it in the next part of the code, if/when needed, even if the environment to be checked changed. In the second variant, you cannot...

Comment: The standard way of minimising the impact of variables on the locals window is to locate them in a module level UDT.  You get one entry in the locals window for the udt, but unless you expand the udt you won't see the value of its fields.